# Network Programming in C (simple server demo code confusion)

Tags: c, networking

I'm learning from the book Hacking, the Art of Exploitation by Jon Erickson, and I am confused regarding to a simple code sample that he provided. The code is to set up a simple server, but when I complied it (no error) and ran the code, it hangs

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include "hacking.h"

#define PORT 7890   // the port users will be connecting to

int main(void) {
int sockfd, new_sockfd;  // listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_fd
struct sockaddr_in host_addr, client_addr;  // my address information
socklen_t sin_size;
int recv_length=1, yes=1;
char buffer[1024];

if ((sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    fatal("in socket");

if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1)
    fatal("setting socket option SO_REUSEADDR");

host_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;      // host byte order
host_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);    // short, network byte order
host_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // automatically fill with my IP
memset(&(host_addr.sin_zero), '\0', 8); // zero the rest of the struct

if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&host_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    fatal("binding to socket");

if (listen(sockfd, 5) == -1)
    fatal("listening on socket");

while(1) {    // Accept loop
    sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    new_sockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &sin_size);
    if(new_sockfd == -1)
        fatal("accepting connection");
    printf("server: got connection from %s port %d\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
    send(new_sockfd, "Hello World!\n", 13, 0);
    recv_length = recv(new_sockfd, &buffer, 1024, 0);
    while(recv_length > 0) {
        printf("RECV: %d bytes\n", recv_length);
        dump(buffer, recv_length);
        recv_length = recv(new_sockfd, &buffer, 1024, 0);
    }
    close(new_sockfd);
}
return 0;
}
```

I did a little printf() to find out where I hangs, and it turns out to be on this line

```
sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
```

I'm not sure if it has to do with my environment, or there is something that I am missing. The environment that the book uses can no longer be updated (some old verson of Ubuntu). So I am currently using the latest one.

Can someone please explain to me why the program does not work?

And if there is some basic that need to know before learning the network chapter, please do tell.

Comment: I don't believe it hangs in that line. Is it possible that it hangs on the next line? Did you try to connect to this server using a client?

Comment: By using another client you mean opening another terminal and using the telnet command? If so, then yes I did. I am just following the books command line inputs.

Comment: I did telnet 192.168.42.248 7890, but I cannot connect.

Comment: And 192.168.42.248 is whose IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telling by all the comments flying around in your thread I'd recommend to connect with telnet using the following command line: `telnet localhost 7890`

telnet takes as arguments the host to connect to and the port to connect to on this host. Using "localhost" is similar to using the loopback IP 127.0.0.1.

Why does connecting to the server solve the "hang"? accept is blocking as you can read in the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/accept) or any other documentation of your programming environment. This means the function won't return until a client connects. After connecting the function returns a handle to the socket created for the connecting client which can be used to communicate.

Answer (score 2):

This program won't proceed until `accept` on the line after the `sizeof` receives an incoming connection from a client program. Your printf shows that accept was called but was blocked.

You need to compile and run the client with the right options (IP / Port) to connect to this server program.

**Update**
If 192.168.42.248 is from the book, then you're probably trying to connect to the wrong IP. Try `telnet 127.0.0.1 7890`.

Comment: The Port is given by the book, so I don't quit understand how that works. And as for the IP, the book using IPv4. Is there a conflict with the IP that I am using? Also not sure how that works.

Comment: Try what @fons suggests before. That should connect to your server.

Comment: To connect to your machine, you need to use its IP address or in your case 127.0.0.1 which addresses the loopback interface. I suggest you read up on IP addressing.

Answer (score 2):

It's a server, it will "hang" until you make a connection to port 7890. That's the whole point of the program (for more detais, it blocks since [`accept()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/accept) is waiting for a connection)

Assuming you are running unix, try to type `echo "hi there" | nc localhost 7890` in a terminal from the same machine while you run it, and you will see how it "unblocks"

Comment: I got "Hello world!"...., but how to use telnet command? I cannot connect. For clarification, the book used telnet command, then type some word when connect, then ran the ./a.out and more info is displayed

Comment: @fons telling by the comments of Jack he is already trying to connect to the server using telnet.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for which you need to use `telnet` instead of `nc` ?

Just type `nc localhost 7890` and start typing, you should get the same behaviour.

Comment: `telnet localhost 7890` should be equivalent

Comment: @jack whose IP is 192.168.42.248? Is that from the book?

Comment: No specific reason, just following the book. nc localhost works

Comment: You must use your IP address or hostname. Try `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: @Jack I'd recommend to read a little bit about networking before starting with "Hacking". There are various articles around in the web

Comment: I still cannot connect when I use my own IP

Comment: How are you figuring out your IP? Do not use your public internet IP (the one shown in `http://www.whatismyip.com/`) since, assuming you are conntectd through a router, that will be your router's address.

try doing `nc 127.0.0.1 7890` or using your local private ip instead (shown by the ifconfig command)

Comment: @junix, I am decent at programming (data structures and OO), but where can I start with programming in networks and such?

Comment: @Jack you should start another question for that, it is out of the scope of this one as I see it. Stackoverflow is not a forum :)

Comment: @Jack Start with learning about TCP/IP first in order to understand how to interact over the network. E.g. understanding what IP addresses and ports are for, etc. Maybe this one is a starter: http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/Networks/Intro/NetIntro.pdf But I have to admin I didn't read it through. But telling by the chapters it seems to cover the minimum